# flash for desktop

Tags: air, flash

I have developed some online flash games that communicate with PHP server files.
As we all know it, flash games can be used only if embedded on a website or by launching the SWF file from desktop, using a Flash player.

However, no method makes the game secure. I mean if you have access to the SWF you can decompile it anyway and steal everything at any time. It can be done easy or hard, depending on how good the game is protected, but it can be done.

I would like to know if there would be possible to embed/encrypt flash SWF files into a desktop application, and create a desktop application that will allow the games to be played from desktop only, but keeping the SWF files 100% secure.

Comment: It will never be 100% secure. Best example is copy protection. If there is a strong need to crack something, it will happen. A solution might be moving the secret parts to the server, it that is an option.

Comment: But it can be done ? How ? Would it be at least 10x times more secure ? Considering someone needs 1 week to decompile a flash game ... if it were to be used as embeded into a desktop app, would that person require like 4-5 weeks to crack it, isntead of 1 week normally ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SWF2EXE tool to encrypt you Flash game. Take a look at [ZINC](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/), for instance. I used the old version (3.0) and it was possible to build standalone applications for Windows, Mac and Linux. It had (and certainly has) options to limit the use to a certain period of time, make trials or even provide serial numbers to your applications. It is a commercial tool, but you can download the trial to check out if it solves your problems.

In the end, this doesn’t protect your code 100%, but it is not as easy to extract the code.

Comment: @nevergone: If you found your solution, please post it. Thx

Comment: I wanted to create something like a game gallery, where people would choose which game to open. ZINC is good, but I also have to develop a desktop app to launch each EXE file when the player wants to play any game. However .EXE is much safer than .SWF in my opinion.